# Difference between putting primitive or object to an object map in Java

Tags: java, object, hashmap, double, primitive-types

I have a simple map:

```
Map<String, Object> myMap;
```

And I am just wondering, what is the difference between these two solutions:
First, when I put my `double` value as a `Double` object:

```
myMap.put("object", Double.valueOf(myPrimitiveDouble));
```

Second when I put my `double` value as a primitive type:

```
myMap.put("primitive", myPrimitiveDouble);
```

I think the first one is unnecessary, am I right?
Thanks for the answers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you put your primitive `double` as a value into your `Map<String, Object>`, it will automatically be boxed into a `Double` type, as generic collections (that includes maps) do not use primitives.

This is called [autoboxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html).

Therefore, the `Double.valueOf` invocation is indeed redundant in this case.

**Example**

```
Map<String, Object> myMap = new HashMap<>();
double foo = 5;
myMap.put("", foo);
System.out.println(myMap.get("").getClass());
```

**Output**

```
class java.lang.Double
```

**Note**

Java will auto-box your primitive `double` to `Double` when the collection is parametrized with either `Object`, `Number` or `Double`.

Your code would not compile, however, if your map values were parametrized with an incompatible type, e.g. `Integer`.

Comment: sorry, but first you say "do not use primitives", and then "it is indeed redundant in this case", so maybe I misunderstand something..

Comment: @victorio the **Java collections** do not use primitives. **You** can use primitives, that will in turn be autoboxed into their object wrappers, if compatible with your generic parametrization.

Comment: ah ok, now it is clear! thank you so much! and also double primitive cannot be null, so I cannot put null into the map, right?

Comment: @victorio you're welcome. You are right in saying primitives are not nullable, however, you *can* put `null` values in most Java maps (with some exceptions, e.g. `ConcurrentSkipListMap`).